# Unwanted button preview before animation during transition to second controller

Tags: ios, swift, transition, uiviewanimation

In a navigation controller embedded project, using animations, I cannot avoid getting a "fast preview" of the buttons present in the next ViewController, where those buttons will slide from left border of the screen to the center.

So, when I tap in first VC, see for an instant the buttons in second VC, and then the second VC appears and the animation works (and it works fine)

In home controller the button is:

```
   @objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print("tapped")

        //animate 1/2
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.mainButtonContainerView.center.y -= self.view.bounds.width //self.view.frame.origin
            self.mainButtonContainerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            self.mainButtonContainerView.alpha = 0.0
        })

        //animate2/2


  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1) ) {
        self.pushShowNextVC_ChoiceVC(dataToPass: "")

    }

}
```

Then, the animation in second VC ViewDidLoad is:

```
    for singleView in coantinersOutCollection {
        //animation
        singleView.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
        singleView.layer.cornerRadius = singleView.bounds.size.height/2
        singleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        singleView.layer.borderColor = Constants.skyBlue3Color.cgColor
        singleView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }

    for singleLabel in labesForButtons {

        singleLabel.textColor = Constants.skyBlue3Color
        singleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)

    }

    for singleImage in self.iconButtonImages {

//            singleImage.image = UIImage(named: "")
            singleImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            singleImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
            singleImage.layer.borderColor = Constants.skyBlue3Color.cgColor


    }


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.6,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                   options: [], animations: {

                    self.containerDownloadButton.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.7,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                   options: [], animations: {

                    self.containerUploadButton.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.8,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                   options: [], animations: {

                    self.containerCallButton.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.9,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                   options: [], animations: {

                    self.containerIdleButton.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

    }, completion: nil)
```